# Spring HttpInputMessage encoding

Tags: java, spring

Is there any way to get the content encoding from the `[HttpInputMessage][1]` into a `HttpMessageConverter`? I browsed the documentation but I cannot find any relevant info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want. If by encoding you mean the `Content-Encoding` or `Content-Type` header, then all you have to do is

```
HttpInputMessage inputMessage = ...;
HttpHeaders headers = inputMessage.getHeaders();
MediaType contentType = headers.getContentType();
String contentEncoding = headers.getFirst("content-encoding"); // it's case insensitive
```

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you, corrected. I don't think it's ever returned String, I must have been writing in a hurry :p